# Mousemove events are not triggered when I drag the scroll bar with the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to detect mouse movement on the drag of my websites scroll bar, this allows me to detect user inactivity.

When the scroll bar is being dragged the mouse move event is not firing.

Not working in IE11 and Chrome, I'm seeing the mousemove events fire in Firefox 32, I have not tested other browsers.

Sample code:

HTML

```
<div class="parent" style="background-color:black;width:100px;height:500px;overflow:scroll;">
    <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;width:100px;height:1000px"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var lastMove;
$(window).mousemove(function (e) {
    lastMove = new Date();
     $(".child").css("background-color", "red");

    lastTimeMouseMoved = new Date().getTime();
       var t=setTimeout(function(){
           var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
           if(currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved > 10){
               $(".child").css("background-color", "blue");
           }
       },10);
 });
```

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/btdxha8k/

Binding to the scroll event is the solution I currently have but I was wondering if there is a more clean solution as I need to bind to 100+ div's that do not need scrolling events as this looks really redundant, dirty and I normally don't like using hacks like this in my code.

Cheers ;)

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't remove the `onscroll` handler from the scroll bar when its automatic movement is started, and to re-apply the onscroll handler when the automatic movement is stopped. You can't fire an event that isn't attached.. Thus, the only time the event will fire your handler is when the user initiated the scrolling.

Comment: Yup, you only find out about mouse events in the client-area. The scroll-bar is not part of the client-area of the window.

Comment: I'm seeing the mousemove events fire in Firefox 32,

Comment: If that doesn't help you with *all* of the browsers you need to target, you'd be best forgetting this trivia and concentrating on an approach that does work in all target environments. This is unfortunately, the nature of the beast when working with the web. :(

Answer (score 2):

Mouse move event is triggered only when you move mouse within the screen.
Your issue here scrollbar is not the inner side of screen where mouse move event is captured so you shoul add scroll event with the same function

Comment: @Xela i dont think in modern age this will make so huge performance issue  just a scroll event

Comment: yeah I mean its kinda redundant binding mouse move events to overflowed elements that do not need them. I like to make my code look pretty and less confusing for anyone else that needs to maintain it.

Comment: @Xela if to talk about performance i first of all advise you to get rid of jquery there are simpler pure js functions for many jquery alternatives you can use them without filling ram with jquerys variables

Comment: I don't mind performance as much as having nice code that isn't hacky to do a simple function. I like to make my code an art and having redundant scroll events in every scrollable div that doesn't need them seems really dirty.

Comment: @Xela i like completely opposite :) messy and spaceship-like code i like :D

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that mouse events aren't raised because the scrollbar is technically outside of your page.

Instead, could you listen for the `onscroll` event?

https://api.jquery.com/scroll/